# Как добавить редирект, если пользователь зарегистрирован на сайте, но не зашел в свою учетную запись?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, redirect

У меня есть код, который определяет условие для перенаправления пользователя.

На данный момент, если пользователь не зарегистрирован и не добавил продукт из определенной категории (подписка), его перенаправляет на регистрацию, а затем на страницу для редактирования учетной записи.

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect');

function woo_custom_redirect($redirect) {
    // HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
    $category = 'subscriptions';

    $found = false;

    // CHECK CART ITEMS: search for items from our product category
    foreach(WC() - > cart - > get_cart() as $cart_item) {
            if (has_term($category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'])) {
                    $found = true;
                    break;
            }
    }

    if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && $found) {
            wp_redirect('/my-account/edit-account/');
            exit();
    }

    if (is_user_logged_in() && !WC() -> cart -> is_empty() && is_account_page()) {
            wp_redirect(get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id')));
    }

}
```

Мне нужно добавить условия:

Если пользователь зарегистрирован, но не вошел в свой аккаунт и добавил продукт из определенной категории (подписка), он перенаправляется на форму входа в систему и, когда он вводит данные, возвращается в корзину.

Если пользователь зарегистрирован, зашел под своей учетной записью и добавил товар из определенной категории (подписка), он может его оформить без каких-либо редиректов.

Я добавил код:

```
if (is_user_logged_in() && !WC() -> cart -> is_empty() && is_account_page()) {
        wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_checkout_page_id') ) );
}
```

К сожалению, это не работает. Код представленный ниже, перестает работать:

```
if (!is_user_logged_in() && is_checkout() && $found) {
    wp_redirect('/my-account/edit-account/');                
    exit();
}
```

Вместо страницы для редактирования учетной записи, пользователь перенаправляется на страницу оформления заказа.

Как это можно исправить? Возможно, добавленный мною код, некорректен?

**Update:** На текущий момент у меня несколько условий для покупки товаров.

1. Если пользователь не зарегистрирован и он покупает любой товар, кроме подписки, он спокойно оформляет заказ и система автоматически создает ему аккаунт.
2. Если пользователь зарегистрирован, но забыл войти под своим логином, он также спокойно оформляет заказ, просто войдя под своим логином на странице оформления заказа.
3. Если пользователь не зарегистрирован и хочет купить подписку, его перекидывает на регистрацию, оттуда на страницу редактирования профиля и он возвращается обратно на оформление заказа.
4. Теперь мне нужно зарегистрированного, но не вошедшего под своим логином пользователя, который хочет купить подписку, перенаправить на форму входа. А оттуда вернуть на страницу оформления заказа.

Comment: "Если пользователь зарегистрирован, но не вошел в свой аккаунт" - этот как?

Comment: @KAGGDesign Я обновил свой вопрос.

Comment: Если пользователь разлогинился сам или сработал тайм-аут или просто закрыл вкладку в браузере, то его сессия уничтожается. Это аксиома! Вы вот пишите :"пользователь долго не заходил" - это что значит??!!))) У вас на сайте явно нарушения политики безопасности, переустановите движок и снесите все плагины, которые имеют малый рейтинг в репозитарии. Ну и все платные плагины - должны быть куплены, тут для не-программиста без вариантов...

Comment: Да что вы придираетесь к словам? Я ошибся с сессией. Если не можете помочь с данным вопросом, зачем вообще что-то писать?

Comment: Если за ПК сидели несколько человек, они логинились/выходили. Какой пользователь считается зарегистрированным, а какой нет? Как с точки зрения не авторизованного пользователя определить его "зарегистрированость"?

Comment: Вот и я хотел бы знать.